# Make a div in in one window visible on click of a button in another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one html page (static html). Inside that I have anchor tag (`.windowOpener`), and a hidden div(`.status`) which shows the status. When user clicks the anchor tag, a window gets opened:

```
     <a href="#" class='windowOpener' onClick="window.open('newPage.html','New Page','resizable,height=580px,width=357px'); return false;">Click here</a>
<div class='status' style='display:none'>Successful</div>
```

On click of this link, a separate window gets opened. In this new window, there is one link as

```
<a class='paymentButton' href='javascript:void(0)'>Do the payment</a>
```

Now on click of this anchor tag (.paymentButton), I want to close the new window and want to make the 'status' div visible in the first window. I don't want to use the modals.

Is it possible to do this? Any help will be appreciated...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.parent` to access the parent window:

```
$(document).on('click', '.paymentButton', function() {
    parent.showStatusDiv();
});
```

And declare `showStatusDiv()` function in the parent window:

```
function showStatusDiv() {
    $('.status').show();
}
```

**NOTE**

In case of more that one level of windows, use `window.top` to access the top most window

Comment: thank you @kapantzak for your suggestion.
somehow it is not working. I tried with 
parent.showStatusDiv(); 
and also with 
window.parent.showStatusDiv();

But it is giving me error as:
 
Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.showStatusDiv is not a function

pl note that i am not using any iframe